# PDMENU application missing in 22.04

Tags: command-line, launcher, 22.04

Is there any reason to remove **PDMENU** application from version  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Was it done consciously or is it a mistake?

Is there any recommended replacement for it that work in terminal?

Comment: This site is run by volunteers, not devs. Questions that ask for speculation are improper here and likely off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not speak for this specific package or software, but the reason an application is removed from the software center commonly is that

1. it appears not to be maintained anymore and, especially,
2. it uses libraries that are outdated and not anymore supported on newer versions.